# What is the deciding factor for react dev tools to say that a particular react version used in a website is outdated?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-devtools

React Developer Tools shows a message that i'm using an outdated version of react. I'm using 0.14.2 which is very old. But updating react to the latest version will break a lot of code. I want to upgrade react to the version that is not considered outdated as of now, and consider upgrading to latest some time later.

I feel 15.6.2 is the best i can upgrade to with out code changes. But how do i know if that version is also outdated according to React Developer Tools?

Answer (score 0):

With the current plugin version, they check for various conditions. As of today anything 15 and earlier (less than 16) is considered to be **"outdated"** by the plugin.

To look at the specific details [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/faa4b630a8c055d5ab4ff51536f1e92604d5c09c/backend/installGlobalHook.js#L111) is the code `(line number 111)`.

```
// Seems like we're using the production version.
// However, the branch above is Stack-only so this is 15 or earlier.
return 'outdated';
```

React 16 was a major rewrite under the hood with changes related to the core architecture known as `React-Fibre`, which contains performance enhancements. It also is the first version to be released with the `MIT` license, hence recommended.